# Cannot Send Email in AppEngine Tutorial

Tags: android, google-app-engine, servlets, firebase

I am simply following the tutorial outlined in: https://cloud.google.com/solutions/mobile/firebase-app-engine-android-studio, section **Add the backend module**.

The Servlet code I have is:

```
import com.firebase.client.DataSnapshot;
import com.firebase.client.Firebase;
import com.firebase.client.FirebaseError;
import com.firebase.client.ValueEventListener;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.util.Properties;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

import javax.mail.Message;
import javax.mail.MessagingException;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.Transport;
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

public class MyServlet extends HttpServlet {
    static Logger Log = Logger.getLogger("com.example.username.myapplication.backend.MyServlet");

    @Override
    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
            throws IOException {
        Log.info("Got cron message, constructing email.");

        //Create a new Firebase instance and subscribe on child events.
        Firebase firebase = new Firebase("[firebase-DB]");
        firebase.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                // Build the email message contents using every field from Firebase.
                final StringBuilder newItemMessage = new StringBuilder();
                newItemMessage.append("Hello main user");


                //Now Send the email
                Properties props = new Properties();
                Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, null);
            try {
                Message msg = new MimeMessage(session);
                //Make sure you substitute your project-id in the email From field
                msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress("anything@firebasebackendserver.appspotmail.com",
                        "Todo Nagger"));
                msg.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO,
                        new InternetAddress("myEmail@gmail.com", "Recipient"));
                msg.setSubject("Good Morning!");
                msg.setText(newItemMessage.toString());
                Transport.send(msg);
            } catch (MessagingException | UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                Log.warning(e.getMessage());
            }
            }

            public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {
            }
        });
    }

}
```

And the `cron.xml` file as:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<cronentries>
    <cron>
        <url>/hello</url>
        <description>Send me an email of outstanding items in the morning</description>
        <schedule>every 1 minutes</schedule>
    </cron>
</cronentries>
```

After completing an in Firebase, the AppEngine dashboard does register that a request has occurred, however, the email is never sent, all I see in the logs is the error:

```
Caused by: com.google.apphosting.api.ApiProxy$FeatureNotEnabledException: The Socket API will be enabled for this application once billing has been enabled in the admin console.
```

Even though I have already enabled billing for this app.

Is there some sort of grace period after billing is enabled before you can actually begin to use it...?

What is wrong with the code layout?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you're sending from a disallowed sender. Here's an excerpt from the [docs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/mail/#Python_Sending_mail):

For security purposes, the sender address of a message must be one of the following:

- The Gmail or Google Apps Account of the user who is currently signed in
- Any email address of the form anything@appname.appspotmail.com or anything@appalias.appspotmail.com
- Any email address listed in the Cloud Platform Console under [Email API Authorized Senders](https://console.cloud.google.com/appengine/settings)

If this is the case, you will see an error in the [logs](https://console.cloud.google.com/logs).

Comment: also, you can whitelist allowed senders from this page - https://console.cloud.google.com/appengine/settings

Comment: I really need to get this working, can we enter a chat please?

Comment: try using an appspotmail.com address instead. so, if your appid is myawesomeapp, set your sender as fred@myawesomeapp.appspotmail.com. that should work. if that works, then you have something to build on.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104598/discussion-between-gwyn-howell-and-sauron).